# PHP mkdir of a SPLFileObject

Tags: php, mkdir, splfileobject

I'm trying to create n directories based on a TXT file using this code:

```
<?php

$file = new SPLFileObject('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/artists_report/2014/artists.txt');
foreach ($file as $line) {
    mkdir($line);
}

?>
```

What I expect is mkdir assigning a namefolder based on each line I've got in artists.txt <- $line, but 
the directories are created without names and I can't understand why mkdir is not taking $line as a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: @RocketHazmat might not work as there is no mode parameter on windows.

Comment: @Shawn: `/Applications/MAMP`.  Looks like a Mac.  Also, the `recursive` parameter works fine on Windows.  The `mode` parameter is just simply ignored.

Comment: I think there is a couple things going on here. The first is that new SPLFileObject is going to give an object and not a string. The second might be file permissions in that directory.

Comment: @RocketHazmat did not realize its ignored in windows. good to know thanks.

Comment: @Shawn: `SplFileObject` is an iterator, so it can be looped over, as is being done here.  I mis-read the question.  He wants to create folders based off the lines in the fie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`file`**](http://php.net/file) instead of `SPLFileObject`

```
$file = file('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/artists_report/2014/artists.txt');
foreach ($file as $line) {
    mkdir($line);
}
```

This assumes that each line in `artists.txt` is a full path name

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filedirectory = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/artists_report/2014/';
//read from your file using SPLFileObject
...some code that is setting $line with a value but converts back to a string...
//i would make $line an array or something so you can simply do:

foreach ($line AS $artist) {
    mkdir($filedirectory.$artist);
}

?>
```